# dlib on Qt Windows. The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, gnu, dlib

I try to use dlib in Qt project on Windows. After downloading I did this in the dlib root:

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" 
cmake --build . --config Release
```

And this(again in dlib root):

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\dlib_build
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

My .pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = dlibWin2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "D:\dlib_build\include"
LIBS += -L"D:\dlib_build\lib" -ldlib
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /arch:AVX
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    try
    {
        frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "\nexception thrown!" << endl;
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Compilation output for MSVC2015 64bit Release:

```
D:\dlib_build\include\dlib\config.h:19: Warning: C4005: DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
```

Runtime output for MSVC2015 64bit Release:

> The program has unexpectedly finished... Exited with code -1073741795

Please note that I did this after Windows reinstalling, and before this I got absolutely the same issue.

How can I solve this or how can I use dlib in Qt on Windows?

Comment: please post the complete main(), also did you return anything from main?

Comment: @Mikhail thanks for the response, now I posted full main.cpp with full main().

Comment: So, can you remove the qt part code from main()? It seems unnecessary for a minimal reproducible example. Also what CPU are you using?

Comment: Is it possible you don't have the DLL in the built application folder?

Comment: @fassl but which dll? I linked dlib staticly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you dont see an exception output - the problem should be in **/arch:AVX** part. May be your processor does not support AVX instructions. In x64 mode SSE2 will be enabled automatically

Try this .pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = dlibWin2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "D:\dlib_build\include"
LIBS += -L"D:\dlib_build\lib" -ldlib
```

No need to rebuild examples and dlib. 
-DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT removed because you have C4005 warning.

You are one one step from success!

Comment: Thanks, I will check it

Comment: WOW! Finally it works! But this a bit strange, I thought I tried this option...
Anyway, thanks one more time :)